# Add as many cards as there are values after query

Tags: jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, materialize

I am trying to create as many [Materializecss cards](http://materializecss.com/cards.html) as there are values after Firebase query.

E.g I do in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var brandsRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Brands");
    brandsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    //Append cards here card title would be childKey
    });
    });
});
```

If the `childKey = 5`, I want that 5 cards appears with the `childKey value`.

I know that I can append lists like this:

```
$(".collection").append('<a href="index.html" class=" collection-item">'+childKey+'</li>');
```

but do not know how to nest for the cards.

Comment: You need create the cards into your key iterator (snapshot.foreach). The data of those cards is coming by an ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer with pure js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var i = 0;
   var cardsObject = [{
       title: "Title 1",
       content: "Content 1",
     }, {
       title: "Title 2",
       content: "Content 2",
     }, {
       title: "Title 3",
       content: "Content 3",
     }];

     while (i < cardsObject.length) {
       var yourData = i;
       createCard(cardsObject[i])
       i++;
     };

     function createCard(cardObject) {
       var divCard = document.createElement("div");
       divCard.setAttribute("class", "card");
       var divCardContent = document.createElement("div")
       divCardContent.setAttribute("class", "card-content");
       var divCardTitle = document.createElement("span")
       divCardTitle.setAttribute("class", "card-title");
       var link = document.createElement("a");
       link.setAttribute("href", "index.html");
       link.setAttribute("class", "collection-item");
       var parag = document.createElement("p");
       link.innerHTML = "Botão 1";
       parag.innerHTML = cardObject.content;
       divCardTitle.innerHTML = cardObject.title;

       divCardContent.appendChild(divCardTitle);
       divCardContent.appendChild(parag);
       divCardContent.appendChild(link);
       divCard.appendChild(divCardContent);
       document.getElementsByClassName("collection").appendChild(divCard);
     }
   });
```

Here's the code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramon_schmidt/5fqgbvzw/10/)

Comment: Awesome solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a problem with the nesting of the card, just copy the whole html structure into your `.append()` function:

```
    $(".collection").append("<div class='row'><div class='col s12 m6'><div class='card blue-grey darken-1'><div class='card-content white-text'><span class='card-title'>Card Title</span><p>" + childKey + "</p></div><div class='card-action'> <a href='#'This is a link</a> <a href='#'This is a link</a> </div> </div> </div></div>");
```

a simplified [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fqgbvzw/)